# Clause to add where value is in array query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this piece of code which i use in order to get all the values inside a column
And save them in an array.

```
$sektori="SELECT * FROM userss WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'" 
or die(mysql_error());  
$resektor = odbc_exec($connection, $sektori) or die(odbc_error());
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resektor) ) {
$ids_sektor = explode("/",$row['sektori']);
}
```

I need to add this condition here:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT formas.*, SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,SMS_SERVISI.time_added
FROM formas 
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET WHERE formas.data_fillim >= '$yesterday' AND formas.data_fillim <= '$tomorrow' AND  sektori_pergjegjes IN ($ids_sektor) ORDER BY formas.id DESC";
```

It says i have a syntax error, but i don't know..maybe i'm doinf the wrong thing, help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does it say there's a syntax error?

Comment: it says: Invalid column name 'Array'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition to that one:

```
"AND  sektori_pergjegjes IN ('" . implode('\',\'', $ids_sektor) . "')"
```

Comment: Show the query that is generated into `$strSQL` with my change

Comment: $strSQL = "SELECT formas.*, SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,SMS_SERVISI.time_added
FROM formas 
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET WHERE formas.data_fillim >= '$yesterday' AND formas.data_fillim <= '$tomorrow' AND  sektori_pergjegjes IN (" + implode(',', $ids_sektor) + ") ORDER BY formas.id DESC";

Comment: OK, check now - replaced `+` with `.`

Comment: Please one question, so i echo it and i get this result

SELECT formas.*, SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,SMS_SERVISI.time_added FROM formas LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET WHERE formas.data_fillim >= '20130227' AND formas.data_fillim <= '20130301' AND formas.sektori_pergjegjes IN (B) ORDER BY formas.id DESC

Comment: Finally :):)
Thanks very much!